# 3D cubes slowly rendering

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, camera, render

My previous problem was fixed after I rewrote my block.cs class, however, I have one final problem:

I have a list of 256 blocks each with 12 triangles and 36 vertices. When I am rendering these blocks using:

```
blocks.ForEach(block => block.Draw(spriteBatch, camera, effect));
```

They do render, but the game speed drops intensely, to about 0.25 FPS. Each block has a different texture. Should 3072 triangles and 9216 vertices cause this much of a problem?

My render code:

```
    public void Render(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        if (!isConstructed) ConstructBlock();

        using (var buffer = new VertexBuffer(graphicsDevice, VertexPositionNormalTexture.VertexDeclaration, NUMVERTICES, BufferUsage.WriteOnly))
        {
            buffer.SetData(vertices);
            graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(buffer);
        }

        graphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, NUMTRIANGLES);
    }
```

My cube's Draw code:

```
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Camera camera, BasicEffect effect)
    {


        effect = new BasicEffect(spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice)
        {
            TextureEnabled = true,
            Texture = Texture,
            View = camera.View,
            Projection = camera.Projection,
            World = Matrix.Identity
        };


        effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
        foreach (var pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            Render(spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to wade through your code. Use the debugger.

Comment: Creating a vertex buffer (or even multiple) in each frame is whole bunch of work that is probably causing the performance problems. Create the buffer once and reuse it. Maybe you only need one buffer for all cubes and just change the world matrix.